# Find $\dim(W_{1} \cap W_{2} \cap W_{3})$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $$W_{1}=\{(x,y,z)| x+y-z=0\}$$; $$W_{2}=\{(x,y,z)| 3x+y-2z=0\}$$; $$W_{3}=\{(x,y,z)| x-7y+3z=0\}$$

Find the $\dim(W_{1}\cap W_{2}\cap W_{3}).$

My solution- I know how to find $\dim(W_{1}\cap W_{2})=\dim W_{1} + \dim W_{2}-\dim(W_{1}+W_{2}).$ But can we extend this further or is there any simpler way to find this.

Comment: To extend it you can define $V:=W_1\cap W_2$ and apply your result to $V\cap W_3$. Another way to do it is the one shwed in the answer

Comment: @Giulio Thanks! So, going by the following solution answer would be 2 itself ? I couldn't quite understand what's the need of Rank Nullity Theorem as answered by egreg.

Comment: The intersection will have dimension $n-r(A) = 3-2=1$ where $A$ is the matrix and $n$ is the number of variables.

Answer (score 3):

The intersection is the solution space of
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y-z=0\\
3x+y-2z=0\\
x-7y+3z=0
\end{cases}
$$
that is, the null space of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
3 & 1 & -2 \\
1 & -7 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which has rank $2$, as an easy elimination will prove. The rank-nullity theorem now helps.

Comment: Oh..yup thanks, a lot simpler way. But, the answer $dim(W_1 \cap W_2 \cap W_3)$ would be 2 itself. Whats the use of rank nullity theorem ?

Comment: @user18900 Since the rank is $2$, the null space has dimension $3-2=1$.